# C++: rvalue reference constructor and copy-elision

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand the rvalue reference constructor and assignment operator.  I created the following source code which should invoke the **rvalue reference constructor**, however it doesn't occur.  My suspicion is copy-elision optimization is the cause.  Does anyone know if that's the reason?  Also, if **copy-elision** is the cause, what is the point of of rvalue references in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    X() : v{new vector<int>(0)} { }
    X(const X&);
    X(X&&);
    X& operator=(const X& rhs);
    X& operator=(X&& rhs);
private:
   vector<int> *v;
};

X::X(const X& a)
{
    cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    for (auto p : *(a.v))
        v->push_back(p);
}

X::X(X&& a) : v{a.v}
{
    cout << "rval ref constructor" << endl;
    a.v = nullptr;
}

X& X::operator=(const X& rhs)
{
    cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
    delete v;
    v = new vector<int>();
    for (auto p : *(rhs.v))
        v->push_back(p);
    return *this;
}

X& X::operator=(X&& rhs)
{
    cout << "rval ref assignment op" << endl;
    swap(v, rhs.v);
    return *this;
}

X f0()
{
    return X(); // copy-elision no move called
    // return move(X());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    X x1(f0());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you observe copy elision. But it's not always possible to elide copies. Try adding `X x2(std::move(x1));` - you should see a move constructor called.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sounds like an answer!

Comment: When coding C++ do you always add the rvalue reference constructor and assignment operator?  Or do you leave these out until some performance is tested and find it necessary?  Thanks

Comment: [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @notaorb: No, you don't. In fact, if you can manage it, you should strive to [avoid defining default methods](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-zero), i.e. "rule of zero" as Igor points out.

Comment: "copy elision"? who comes up with these terms? *smh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to main():

```
X x2(std::move(x1));
```

this manually indicates the object x1 can be moved from to work around copy-elision.  copy-elision is not always invoked, so there may be cases where the rvalue reference constructor and assignment operator are required.